# Regex capturing nonexistent grouping when using `.split`

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string using regex. Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
'a.b.c.e[2].z'.split(/(?:\.)|\[(\d+)\]/g);
```

I'm getting a result of

```
["a", undefined, "b", undefined, "c", undefined, "e", "2", "", undefined, "z"]
```

I expected and want a result of

```
["a", undefined, "b", undefined, "c", undefined, "e", undefined, 2, undefined, "z"]
```

Or even:

```
["a", undefined, "b", undefined, "c", undefined, "e", "2", undefined, "z"]
```

I just don't want that empty string in the results list, other than manually removing this (which I can't do because this is part of a larger regex), is there a way to modify this regex to not have that empty string?

### EDIT

It may be unclear as to what I'm exactly trying to do, here's a snippet of the relavant program:

```
var rawParts = path.split(/\.|\[(\d+)\]|\[(")((?:[^"]|(?:\\.))*)"\]|\[(')((?:[^']|(?:\\.))*)'\]/g);
var rawPart;
var parts = [];
var i, l;
for (i = 0, l = rawParts.length; i < l; i++) {
    rawPart = rawParts[i];
    if (rawPart !== undefined) {
        if (rawParts[i - 1] === '"') {
            rawPart = rawPart.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
        } else if (rawParts[i - 1] === "'") {
            rawPart = rawPart.replace(/\\'/g, "'");
        }
        parts.push(rawPart);
    }
}
```

I simplified the problem I had above but the idea is I want to remove the empty string when I'm matching a `[0]` case. I can't remove all empty string because in a case of `a.b[''].c` the blank string is valid

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why are you parsing that with regex in the first place?

Comment: @elclanrs I'm creating a nested object getting, ex `get(obj, 'foo[4].bar')`

Comment: What is the point of non-capture and capture groups in a `.split()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a key from an object using that string as path, I think you're complicating things. You can do this with a reducer, and knowing that bracket notation works for both arrays an objects, you'd have to transform `e[2]` into `e.2`, then reduce to resolve the path.

```
var obj = {a: {b: {c: {e: [{},{},{z:'found'}]}}}}

var get = function(path, obj) {
  path = path.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, '.$1').split('.')
  return path.reduce(function(a, x){return a && a[x]}, obj)
}

get('a.b.c.e[2].z', obj) //=> found
```

If not found you will get `undefined`.

Comment: This is part of a larger regex that also parses `["foo"]` and `['foo']` notation and also accepts `["foo\"2"]` and `["foo.2"]` so it's not a simple matter to just change the implementation like that

Comment: Your question is not very clear then, as this works with your string on an object as demonstrated. Try posting a real world example, with inputs and outputs, and what you expect. Asking for the regex is the wrong question. Ask about your actual problem, that's why I think you're facing an XY problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to better explain the problem I'm facing